# Powershell Script to deploy the ARM Template

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, wvd

Deploying the ARM Template using the Powershell, need to fetch the previous AVD Session host number from Azure Portal and from which we can pass the next incremental value in the ARM template by declaring a variable.

```
#Login-AzAccount
$vminitialnumber= Get-AzWvdSessionHost -HostPoolName infosyswvd -ResourceGroupName avd 
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
-ResourceGroupName AVD `
-TemplateFile 'D:\Updated-AVD\East US\Template.json' `
-TemplateParameterFile 'D:\Updated-AVD\East US\Parameters.json'
```

Comment: Please first go to this page and identify which API can be used to return "previous AVD session host number" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/desktopvirtualization/

Answer (score 0):

#### Please check the below workaround:

##### Install module

```
Install-Module Az.Avd
Import-Module Az.Avd
```

##### Fetch the Latest Session Host

Use the **[Get-AvdLatestSessionHost](https://github.com/srozemuller/AzAvd/blob/main/Docs/Get-AvdLatestSessionHost.md#get-avdlatestsessionhost)** to get the Latest Session Host.

###### syntax

```
Get-AvdLatestSessionHost -HostpoolName <String> -ResourceGroupName <String> [-NumOnly] [<CommonParameters>]
```

- **NumOnly** - Here you will set the **Switch Parameter**. You will get the next **session host** number.
  -**InputObject** - Here put the **hostpool** object.

###### Example to Get the Latest session Host of ADV

```
Get-AvdLatestSessionHost -HostpoolName <Your Host Pool Name> ResourceGroupName <Your Resource Group Name>
```

Refer this [blog](https://rozemuller.com/how-to-deal-with-avd-session-hosts-version-management/) to get the session Recent/Old Session Host using the **Get-AvdImageVersionStatus** Command.